# Virtualbox Guest Additions are not used

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Today, it seemed in my Ubuntu 14.04 VM (Kubuntu 14.04 host), there was an update for the Guest Additions to 4.3.12, and I was requested to install them from the Devices menu. I did this, but even though the Guest Additions installer ran completely OK (though it looks like it did a "non-kernel" installation), Guest Additions are not working properly and I don't get 3D graphics acceleration.

Is there any way to solve this problem with the latest version of Guest Additions?

Comment: Have you installed it in the VM as well (you have to install in both the guest and host machines)? - the extension pack should show under 'File' > 'Preferences' > 'Extensions' (like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j8YVU.png)) if it installed correctly. You also need to enable it in the settings for the VM ([under the Display tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XiKLo.png))

Comment: Yes the extension pack is installed, as you show in the screenshot. I don't see a setting for using guest additions in the vm settings...

Comment: @Wilf that is wrong - the Guest additions need to be installed in the guest only.